# jqGrid MultiSelect Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I use that when I construct my jqgrid:

```
multiselect: true
```

So I have a check all column. However when I click `check all` checkbox( the checkbox at header) it selects all checkboxes `but the checkboxes are not clicked` at each row. Here is a demo: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and when I click the top checkbox all the checkboes become clicked.

What should I do additionally?

**PS:** I just want that: http://jsfiddle.net/YWVA8/24/ when a user clicks a row that row's checkbox should be clicked, when user clicks click all all the rows should be selected and their checkboxes clicked. Do I use any other paramater that I should not use with multiselect: true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. My id column element was like:

```
User 0
User 1
...
```

I changed it to:

```
User_0
User_1
...
```

because it was not recognizing it as a proper id with whitespace.